# Use undefined instead of null in RealmJS

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm

I am wondering if there is a way to force RealmJS return `undefined` instead of `null` on optional fields?

I am asking this, because typescript's optional types is actually `T | undefined`, not `T | null`. I don't want to mix up `undefined` and `null`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All fields are defined in the schema, there is no possible way to say something is undefined when you have defined that it exists, whether it has a value or not. It makes more sense to say that an optional field is `null` rather than `undefined` because undefined would imply the optional field doesn't even exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it directly in the schema.
For instance:

```
const OrderSchema = {
  name: 'Order',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    table: { type: 'int', optional: true, default: null },
  }
}
```